# How to load more data in UICollectionView without reloading all data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I want to load more data in the collection view when the user reaches the bottom of the collection view, I can control when the user reaches the bottom, and I have an array of 20 items, I want to load 5 of that items and then when the user reaches the bottom load 5 more items of that array until I load 20, but how can I load more data after the last item without refreshing all the collection view?

Comment: you can insert the indexpath in collectionview

Answer (score 0):

Im sure if you change the `numberOfRowsInSection:` return value it should update on its own.

try doing that, otherwise, just `[collectionview reloadData];`, I know you don't want to, but I don't think it loads duplicate data.

And you can check using this:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

since collectionView inherits from scrollView

Comment: Just make it dynamic (i.e the size of the array, and just push the new items to the array, I believe that should update it)
You might have to pair it with '[collectionView reloadDate];'

Comment: Did that word for you?